# Como modificar imagen de background de una web app despues de haber hecho deployment?

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Hice el deployment de una web app, y me di cuenta que la imagen de background que puse en el body vuelve dificil la lectura del contenido, asi que quiero cambiarla, ya intente hacer de nuevo el publish y rebuild pero no ha funcionado de esa manera.

```
<body background="~/Content/fit-gif.gif">
```

fit-gif seria la nueva imagen o gif de back ground en el  **del _Layout.cshtml**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que usar la etiqueta style para agregar css.

**background-image** para asiganarle una imagen de fondo.

**background-size: cover** para asignarle un tamaño total al body.

```
<body style='background-image: url('~/Content/fit-gif.gif');background-size: cover;'>
```

**Actualizado:**  Se agrega `@Url.Content` absoluta

```
<body style='background-image: url(@Url.Content("~/Content/fit-gif.gif"));background-size: cover;'>
```

Comment: Acabo de intentarlo, y no hay cambios.

Comment: Bien, para confirmar algo prueba <body style="background-color: red"> y dime si el fondo, se quedo rojo

Comment: Si, a funcionado.

Comment: pregunta tonta.. cambiaste la imagen que estas mandando?

Comment: No, solo el color, como me sugerio Luciano

Comment: Disculpa, acabo de darme cuenta que tenias una url como absoluta.

Comment: Ahora funciona, gracias.